# Responsive: how do I maintain proportions with stacked divs?

Tags: css, resize, responsive-design

I'm making a responsive site which has a header set to resize. On that image I have to place another, smaller, image at x,y position (it has to link out). My problem is how do I maintain the proportions as the site re sizes? I can define width in percentages, but what about height? ems don't give me enough control for height (unless I have misunderstood how to use them).

```
.gallery { width:100%; position:relative; }
.gallery-over { position:relative;margin:-12.5em 0 0 69%; width:18.5%; }
```

Comment: Could you post some mock-up in relation to your header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly certain you can get by with just adjusting the width of the 'img' tag, but you can also use percentages when dealing the height. It is an accepted method according to W3C. [CSS Height Property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_dim_height.asp) on W3C Schools.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went back and fiddled with it using percentages and got it going. I must have had something wrong with how I was trying to do it before.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do something like this with images:

```
img { width:100%; height:auto; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
```

I find myself needing to set `min-width` and `min-height` too at times, which is better to do on a containing element (IE7, at least, has issues with `height:auto` and min/max widths)